# Internet Explorer bicubic background image rescaling

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm having a bit of trouble with IE downscaling CSS background images using the background: and background-size: attributes, as below

```
.llifLogo {
background: url(images/llifmonotagline.png) no-repeat center;
background-size: 550px;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
width: 100%;
height: 170px;

}
```

The site is live on http://llif.co.uk. Looks great in other browsers, but IE appears to downscale the image using nearest-neighbour rather than bicubic. I understand that there used to be a hack by  using `-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;`, but that this is now deprecated.

Anyone have any ideas how to downscale background images nicely in IE?

I should also add why I want to do a background image rather than just a regular image: it's so that I can use media queries to display a different image when the site is in a narrow viewport such as a mobile device.

Thanks!

Comment: your link is not opening. can you share some screen shots of your UI design?

Comment: Thnaks @GhostAnswer - it should be http://llif.co.uk

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [image-rendering article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)? Seems like there might be a lot in there to come up with a solution to your specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best (and probably the only) way to do this is to resize your .png file.
There's no reason to use 2808x1024 png with file size about 85KB, when you can resize your file to 550x201px and it will have ~15KB and will be nicely rendered. Just use @media queries to switch between pngs with different resolution.